# DateDiff calculation in Tableau

Tags: date, tableau-api, analytics, tableau-desktop

I am trying to calculated the number of days it takes to get approved. So ideally it would show the date diff from Pending review to Approved.

The formula I used to calculated date diff is showing the date diff from the previous row.
This works however I want the calculation to be applied for each Parent ID. Otherwise at the start of each record it is showing a negative date diff because its calculating between 2 different parent ID. [image]

The formula I used to calculated date diff is showing the date diff from the previous row.
This works however I want the calculation to be applied for each Parent ID. Otherwise at the start of each record it is showing a negative date diff because its calculating between 2 different parent ID.

Comment: Hi. Can you add a screen or text of your DateDiff calc?

Comment: Can you please share your sample scenario in a Tableau Public link? It really helps